# Extract parent from a filepath

Tags: java, regex, clojure

I would like to decompose a GCS URI of form :

```
gs://bucket/folder1/folder2/test.csv
```

I need these capturing groups : "bucket" and "folder1/folder2/test.csv"

The problem is that I do not know how to exclude / from a group of any character.

The beginning does not work :

```
^(gs:\/\/){1}(?!\/)
```

I also tried

```
^(gs:\/\/){1}(?!.*\/)
```

I do not understand why it does not work because I saw answer elsewhere and it worked. I use java/clojure.

Thanks !

**EDIT**

My point is to do something like isolating the "bucket" name in my GCS. I tought this would match any string that does not conatin : / :

```
(?!\/)
```

I saw a thread elsewhere but this beginning captured the whole chain after gs:// for me.

Comment: *from a group of any character* - from both groups or what? how should look the captured results?

Comment: *I saw answer elsewhere and it worked* - what do you mean? Can you tell us where you saw it working? Also, try [`^gs:\/\/([^\/]+)\/(.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/2vY4Mg/1) where the parts you seek are *captured*.

Comment: Use `re-groups` to get the captured parts.

Comment: Also mind that you do not need to escape `/` in Java regex patterns, just use `^gs://([^/]+)/(.*) `

Comment: Are you trying with [this](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/re-groups)?

Comment: Thanks for answers. Sorry for the blurry explanation, I meant to capture a string that does not contain / only once. So especially isolating the "bucket" part for instance only once. I saw the answer elsewhere to achieve this goal : (?!.*\/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample in JS to match your require, another language should the same.

```
/^gs:\/\/(.+?)\/(.+)$/
```

Check result [here](http://scriptular.com/#%5Egs%3A%5C%2F%5C%2F(.%2B%3F)%5C%2F(.%2B)%24%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%5B%22gs%3A%2F%2Fbucket%2Ffolder1%2Ffolder2%2Ftest.csv%22%5D)